# В хтмл не отображается запись модели

Tags: python, django

Проблема в том что у меня не отображается запись модели description_text в хтмл
вот код хтмл

`<h1 class="description"><a href="/Homepage/{{ goods.id }}/">{{goods.description_text}}</a></h1>`

вот код models.py

```
class Goods(models.Model):
description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)



def __str__(self):
    return self.description_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.price_text
```

вот код views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'description.description_text'

    def price(self):
        return self.price_text

    def description(self):
        return self.description_text
```

Comment: Вы хоть сами поняли, что написали? Как у вас по вашему мнению должна отображаться модель? Отображается не модель, а её записи. Сформулируйте нормально вопрос и покажите весь шаблон.

Comment: Хорошо, вопрос подправил но шаблон чего показать полностю ?

Comment: Какая необычная реализация... Вы используете ListView, это представление возвращает список объектов из БД.

Comment: Я просил полностью показать шаблон, где отображается содержимое модели.